# Generate heading IDs based on text content, incrementing by 1 for every duplicate

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building an auto-generated TOC in Javascript. Step 1 is to take the text content of every h1-6, strip punctuation and spaces, replace with dashes, and lowercase it, then add that as the `id`, which is what I have here:

```js
function TOC() {
  let h2s = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
  let h3s = document.querySelectorAll("h3");
  let h4s = document.querySelectorAll("h4");
  let h5s = document.querySelectorAll("h5");
  let h6s = document.querySelectorAll("h6");
  let headings = [...h2s, ...h3s, ...h4s, ...h5s, ...h6s];

  function cleanID(content) {
    let trimmed = content.trim();
    let removedPunctuation = trimmed.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    let singleSpacesOnly = removedPunctuation.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
    let spacesToHyphens = singleSpacesOnly.replace(/\W/g, "-");
    let cleanedID = spacesToHyphens.toLowerCase();

    return cleanedID;
  }

  headings.forEach((heading) => {
    heading.id = cleanID(heading.textContent);
  });
}

TOC();
```

This works fine except when it comes to duplicate IDs. What I'd like to do is increment by 1 for every duplicate of each heading, and append that. So for example, if I had

```html
<h2>Foo</h2>
<h3>Bar</h3>

<h2>Foo</h2>
<h3>Baz</h3>
<h4>Bar</h4>
```

I'd like for the IDs to be, respectively, `foo`, `bar`, `foo-2`, `baz`, `bar-2`.

The obvious doesn't seem to work:

```js
var cleanedIDs = [];

function cleanID(content) {
  ...
  let increment = 0;

  if(cleanedIDs.includes(cleanedID) {
    cleanedID = `${cleanedID}-${increment++}`;
    cleanedIDs.push(cleanedID);
  } else {
    cleanedIDs.push(cleanedID);
  }
}
```

Would appreciate help working through the logic of it. [I've started a pen here](https://codepen.io/jacecotton/pen/ZEGbmXL).

Comment: Why are you adding IDs to the headings in the first place? I'm asking because this sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: So that the TOC can link to each heading by its ID. It's step 1 in generating a TOC on a page that doesn't already have heading IDs, so not an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to keep track of the count inside an Object. Then just change the `id` property accordingly.

```js
let headings = [...document.querySelectorAll("h3")];

function headingDups (headings) {
    return headings.reduce((store, heading) => {
        store[heading.textContent] = (store[heading.textContent] || 0) + 1;
        if(store[heading.textContent] > 1) { 
          heading.id = heading.textContent + "-" + store[heading.textContent]
          return store;
        }
        heading.id = heading.textContent;
        return store;
   }, {});
}

headingDups(headings);
```

```html
<h3>hello</h3>
<h3>goodbye</h3>

<h3>h3llo</h3>
<h3>hello</h3>
<h3>h3llo</h3>

<h3>goodbye</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I only have one question now that I've implemented it in my project: what is the empty object as the second argument in the reduce method for? Is it the default value of the `heading` parameter?

Comment: @JaceCotton The simplified explanation is that the second parameter of the `reduce` method defines what `store` is. We're saying *I want to reduce this into an **object*** - the first parameter, the function, describes **how** we want it reduced.